# What's the meaning of 'My' on 'MySQL'?

Tags: mysql

I came across this joke on my newsfeed:

```
"My friend is working on a website and told me he wanted to use MySQL. Why can't he just use HisOwnSQL?"
```

and it got me thinking. What does My in MySQL means?

Comment: you didn't seem to do any research on this... and this question is off topic for stack overflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"MySQL is named after co-founder Monty Widenius's daughter, My."

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/history.html

Comment: beat me by 5 seconds!